# Highlight text in grid using AngularJS filter + ng-repeat in table data

Tags: angularjs

I want to highlight search text under ng-repeat which is creating table.
I found one filter as my solution but it's not working on tables.

Can anyone points me where I am wrong to make it work.

```
<body ng-app="Demo">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="Demo">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">

      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>Some</th>
          <th>MyName</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search"
            >
          <td>
              <td>{{item.title}}</td>
              <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <!-- with filter -->

      </table>
    </div>

    <script>
      angular.module('Demo', [])
        .controller('Demo', function($scope) {
          $scope.data = [
            { title: "Bad",name:'kaushik' },
            { title: "Good",name:'1kaushik' },
            { title: "Great",name:'2kaushik' },
            { title: "Cool" ,name:'3kaushik'},
            { title: "Excellent",name:'4kaushik' },
            { title: "Awesome",name:'5kaushik' },
            { title: "Horrible",name:'6kaushik' },
          ]
        })
        .filter('highlight', function($sce) {
          return function(text, phrase) {
            if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
              '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
          }
        })
    </script>
  </body>
```

[This is working copy of the & demo the same thing I wants is with table.](http://embed.plnkr.co/XbCsxmfrgmdtOAeBZPUp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not applying the `highlight` filter and you also have nested `<td>` elements. Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search">
    <td ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search></td>
    <td ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight:search"></td>
</tr>
```

```js
angular.module('Demo', [])
  .controller('Demo', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        title: "Bad",
        name: 'kaushik'
      },
      {
        title: "Good",
        name: '1kaushik'
      },
      {
        title: "Great",
        name: '2kaushik'
      },
      {
        title: "Cool",
        name: '3kaushik'
      },
      {
        title: "Excellent",
        name: '4kaushik'
      },
      {
        title: "Awesome",
        name: '5kaushik'
      },
      {
        title: "Horrible",
        name: '6kaushik'
      },
    ]
  })
  .filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(text, phrase) {
      if (phrase) {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
          '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
      }
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
    }
  });
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="Demo">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <div class="container" ng-controller="Demo">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Some</th>
        <th>MyName</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search">
          <td>
            <td ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search"></td>
            <td ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight:search"></td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <!-- with filter -->

    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I just added a working snippet. What, specifically, are you not able to get working in your code?