# How to highlight search input when data rendered?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

`searchStr` is user input search keyword , once i rendered response from server i want to highlight user input `searchStr` so user can see what is being searched and compare if its part of response. So below code is highlighting whole string response from server in my case i just want to highlight searched string that will be part of response.

Lets assume i have string

`info|<n/a>|[routes.event] ########## Message added to processing queue ########## e63637db-aa33-4aed-b5b0-51a0764dc7f1 { workerId: 3, pid: 33029 }` and i want to highlight `e63637db-aa33-4aed-b5b0-51a0764dc7f1` _id that will be `searchStr`

main.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages | filter:searchStr" >
                    <td >{{item.filename}}</td>
                    <td class="serverResults" ng-bind-html="item.value | trusted">{{item.value}}</td>
                </tr>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.$on('displaySearchResults',function(e,data){
        $scope.searchStr = data.searchStr;
        $scope.showMessages = data.messageObj;
    })
```

filters.js

```
angular.module('App').filter('trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(text,phrase) {
    if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
                    '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');

       var content = text.toString()
       console.log('Content',content);
       var data = content.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Does [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43188889/548997) help?

Comment: I see this filter before , i dont want to apply filter can we do this in controller

Comment: Controller is not intended to manipulate DOM, use a directive to do this

Comment: Why don't you want to use a filter? In any case, you should be able to apply the same logic in your controller. The benefit of creating a filter is that you are able to use the same functionality in multiple places without having to duplicate the code.

Comment: okay i have added filters to my question that i was using , so thing is if i use `highlight` filter it breaks `trusted` filter functionality. so i was looking something i can implement in controller.

Comment: @hussain 1) Why are you using `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`? That is intended for attributes such as `ng-include` and `src`. 2) If attempting to apply both filters breaks things then combine the functionality into a single filter. If you want to highlight a portion of a string then use the `highlight` filter, otherwise use the `trusted` filter.

Comment: thanks for explanation that definitely make sense, i updated my filter but i still dont see highlighted text. question updated can you help me here..

Comment: Just use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample to show how you might accomplish the highlighting. It is contrived because I'm just creating an array with a single item, but it illustrates the approach. You want to apply your replacement of reserved characters first because if you apply that after you have inserted the highlighted `<span>` the `<` and `>` characters will be stripped by your replacement regex.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showMessages = [{
      value: 'info|<n/a>|[routes.event] ########## Message added to processing queue ########## e63637db-aa33-4aed-b5b0-51a0764dc7f1 { workerId: 3, pid: 33029 }'
    }];
    $scope.searchStr = 'e63637db-aa33-4aed-b5b0-51a0764dc7f1';
  })
  .filter('trusted', function($sce) {
    return function(text, phrase) {
      if (phrase) {
        var data = text.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
        data = data.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
          '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>');
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
      }

      text = text.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
  });
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="searchStr" /></div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages | filter:searchStr">
        <td>{{item.filename}}</td>
        <td class="serverResults" ng-bind-html="item.value | trusted:searchStr"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```