# How to post process bound data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to post process data bound with angularjs?

I am writing simple search page and i have generated results with code:

```
...
<div class="row" ng-repeat="document in sc.searchResult.content">
    <blockquote>
        {{document.content}}
    </blockquote>
</div>
...
```

The problem is that I need to bold specific words in every result (the words from query box - like in google below)

[image]

How to reach that effect?

Comment: is there someone that understood the question ?

Comment: are you asking how to bold a text?

Comment: User is asking how to highlight (in bold) the text of the search results where they match the search terms.

Comment: the above code will show items only if there are already matches in the search, because the ng-repeat seems to run already on the results

Comment: Sorry for unclear descrition. I edited it. JoelCDoyle exactly!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight search input when data rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378643/how-to-highlight-search-input-when-data-rendered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller.js

```
$scope.document.content = someSearchContent.replace(/<searchTerm>/g, '<strong>' + <searchTerm> + '</strong>')
```

`searchTerm` is the string that you need to modify. You can use `RegExp()` to create a regular expresion.

template

```
<blockquote ng-bind-html="document.content"></blockquote>
```